# Qemu network traffic filtering with iptables

Tags: iptables, firewall, qemu, filter, netfilter

I need to filter both outcoming and incoming traffic of the guest system on Qemu (Linux). The host system is Linux too. I think **iptables** is a good tool, but I don't know how to use it here. What command line parameters should I use to run Qemu for correct network interface configuring? How should I use **iptables**? Is **iptables** the best tool?

I need just simple filtering: dropping any packets for example.

Thank You!

Comment: If you can add some more configuration information I think you will be more likely to get useful answers. What is the network topography (what ip does the guest have? host? is the network bridged or NATed between the two?) As written your question is a bit to broad to get actionable answers.

Comment: I just want to block all outcoming and incoming packets of the guest system by iptables running on the host system. Lets look the most simple variant: the single ethernet card, DHCP, no additional bridges, routings and others. I need the 1st solution to begin thinking and working :)

Answer (score 0):

Best and simple, most used iptables management: **ufw**

frontend gui: **gufw**